# Proving that the upper and lower Riemann sums converge to the integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

This is a question from Tom M. Apostol's *Calculus*, Volume 1 (Exercise 10.4):

> $f$ is monotonically increasing and bounded on $[0,1]$. Define the sequences $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ as follows:
>   $$s_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \\
> t_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
>
> a) Prove that $s_n \le \int^1_0 f(x) \mathrm{d}x\le t_n$ and that $0 \le \int^1_0f(x)\mathrm{d}x-s_n \le \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{n}$.
>
> b) Prove that the sequences $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ converge to the limit $\int^1_0f(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Here's what I have tried:

a) We know $s_n$ and $t_n$ are the sum of areas of the rectangles below and above the curve $f$ respectively, the equality holding when $f$ is a piecewise constant function (so $\int^1_0f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ lies between them).

b) The integral is sandwiched between $s_n$ and $t_n$, so when $n\to\infty$, the sums become equal to the integral.

Is there an "analytic" proof for a)?

(I presume an "analytic proof" is one that doesn't make use of the function's graph, though I may be wrong)

Comment: A couple problems, in a) you haven't really proved anything and ignored the second part of the question, and in b) you need a bit more to actually prove that those sequences converge to the integral. For a hint on b) consider the second part of a), what happens when you take $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Silynn I'm using the squeeze/sandwich theorem for part b (as the integral is "squeezed" between $s_n$ and $t_n$, making both approach the integral in-between as $n\to\infty$)

Comment: I was saying you were close, but you haven't proved that they have the same limit, or that the limit of either one is the integral. You can actually do part b) without using $s_n \le \int^1_0 f(x) \mathrm{d}x\le t_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac kn\right) \le \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x) \,\mathrm dx \le\frac{1}{n} f\left(\frac{k+1}n\right).$$
(This is true simply because the values of the function on the whole interval are between the two values.)

If you sum all these inequalities for $k=0,\dots,n-1$ you get
$$s_n \le \int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx \le t_n.$$

This also implies that 
$$0 \le \int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx - s_n \le t_n-s_n.$$
It remains to show that $t_n-s_n=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}n$.

Comment: @VibhavPant Thanks for the correction.

Comment: And, of course, the reason this is true is that, when we talk about "area", the basic property is that if $0 \le f(x) \le g(x)$, the "area" under $f$ is less than the "area" under $g$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Also, wouldn't we need to sum from $k = 0$ (instead of $k=1$) to $n-1$? This way, $1/n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k/n) = s_n$, $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int^{(k+1)/n}_{k/n}f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int^1_0f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and $1/n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f((k+1)/n)=1/n\sum_{k=0}^nf(k/n)=t_n?$

Comment: @VibhavPant Thanks, I have corrected this. It's good that you went through the details.